# What is the difference between 'outstrip' and 'outrun'?

Tags: word-choice

I can't see any difference between 'outstrip' and 'outrun'. I think they have the same meaning but in the gap-filling question

"The economy did very well for a number of years until public expenditure began to **________** tax collected by the government."

the correct answer is 'outstrip', not 'outrun'. Would you be so kind as to clarify this problem for me? Thanks in advance.

(The question is taken from Proficiency multiple choice questions on esl-lounge)

Comment: I'm voting to close as Primarily Opinion-based. In *my* opinion, the test is complete rubbish if it says ***outstrip*** is "correct" and ***outrun*** is "incorrect". They're both perfectly valid usages in this context. Many of the 8000+ written instances of ["began to outrun"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22began+to+outrun%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) are figurative usages involving "supply" and "demand".

Comment: Right.  I could definitely use either one in specific situations, in that sentence.

Answer (score 3):

*Outstrip* means to exceed or surpass in a general sense, while outrun suggests a temporal relationship; something is going faster or farther than something else, and there is a literal or figurative competition.

Comment: I don't see a meaningful difference here. See Oxford Dictionaries Online. [Outstrip](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/outstrip): *move faster than and overtake; exceed.* [Outrun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/outrun): *Run or travel faster or further than; go beyond or exceed.*

Comment: So are the two words interchangeable? Such tests always make me (a non-native speaker) sick.